# sqlalchemy group by unique values in column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a simple model, which looks line this

```
 class Data(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'data'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    sub_id = Column(String)
    value = Column(JSONB)
```

`sub_id` is not unique value. Is it possible to query data from this table grouping rows by `sub_id` with `value` column... something like

```
((sub_id, (all_rows_with_same_sub_id)), (sub_id, (all_rows_with_same_sub_id))
```

Comment: SQL generally doesn't return nested structures.  It's tabular.  Even the even the way you can navigate a record set in your client side code is tabular.  So, you would normally just use `ORDER BY sub_id` to ensure that all rows with the same `sub_id` are next to each other.

Comment: ok, `ORDER BY sub_id` can do the trick... didn't think about it :) thank you